# aar build fails in Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, android-build

We are trying to build aars in Jenkins but they are failing with classes not found.

We have a project with one main (application) and a number of library modules.
When we build the application module we have no problems.
Jenkins builds it perfectly.

However, sometimes we need to build the aars as separate entities to send them as an sdk.

When we try to do that the Jenkins job fails. Claims that a whole load of classes don't exist:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Client-Android-Master/WeFiKeepAliveLibs/app/src/main/java/com/wefi/IWeFiKeepAlive.java:3: error: package android.content does not exist
import android.content.Context;
^
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Client-Android-Master/WeFiKeepAliveLibs/app/src/main/java/com/wefi/IWeFiKeepAlive.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
void init(@NonNull final Context ctx, final WeFiKeepAlive.KeepAliveData keepAliveData);
^
symbol:   class Context
location: interface IWeFiKeepAlive
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Client-Android-Master/WeFiKeepAliveLibs/app/src/main/java/com/wefi/WeFiKeepAlive.java:3: error: package android.content does not exist
import android.content.Context;
^
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Client-Android-Master/WeFiKeepAliveLibs/app/src/main/java/com/wefi/WeFiKeepAlive.java:4: error: package android.os does not exist
```

This happens for all the code.

Following is the gradle file of the module:

```
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply from: '../../WeFiBuild/common/dependencies.gradle'


def computeVersionName() {
    def branch = gitBranch()
    if (branch == "master")
        return "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionRevision}"
    else
        return "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionRevision}.${versionBuild}"
}
ext {
    groupName = 'com.wefi'
    artifactName = 'wefi-keep-alive'
}
apply from: '../../WeFiBuild/common/library_build.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 31

        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0.0'
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        def gitBranch = gitBranch()
        buildConfigField ("String", "BRANCH", "\"${gitBranch}\"")

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compileOnly "androidx.core:core:1.7.0"
    compileOnly "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0"
}
def gitBranch() {
    def branch = ""
    def proc = "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD".execute()
    proc.in.eachLine { line -> branch = line }
    proc.err.eachLine { line -> println line }
    proc.waitFor()
    println "branch name = " + branch
    branch
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

Edit:
An important point to add is that this used to work until we upgraded gradle.
We use the gradle task buildRelease
```

Comment: It would appear that when you build the code as modules, you aren't importing the Android files, specifically the android.content package. Is there any reason you can't build them all together as an SDK?

Comment: There's no `dependencies.gradle` and no `library_build.gradle` - and no dependency on the library module either; also the build task used is unknown. Could flag it as duplicate (which offers a questionable workaround), while the whole project/modules structure appears questionable.

Comment: One thing I forgot to add is that it worked in the past until we upgraded Gradle to 7+

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai Not sure what you mean. When we build the apk we don't get the aars separately. Is there some way of building all the aars from the project level?